# Test spring with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security

I'm trying to run a "integration test" with Spring and Junit, but i'm getting this error:

**java.lang.AssertionError: Authentication should not be null**

My classes:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilterBean() throws Exception {
    final AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter();
    authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManagerBean());
    return authenticationFilter;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

}
```

LoginTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(value = DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@DatabaseSetup("classpath:dbunit/User.xml")
public class LoginTests {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Resource
    private AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter;

@Test
public void login() throws Exception {
    final LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
    loginRequest.setEmail(EMAIL);
    loginRequest.setPassword(PASSWORD);

    mockMvc.perform(post(ENDPOINT)
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(loginRequest))
    ).andExpect(authenticated());
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Authentication should not be null

at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:39)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:72)
at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.response.SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers$AuthenticatedMatcher.match(SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
at br.com.bla.studying.integration.LoginTests.login(LoginTests.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

If i test with postman, everything works fine.
Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101421/null-authentication-during-spring-security-test

Comment: After a wile, i think this is no a problem exactly, look that line: .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) 


if i change to
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)

Spring understand the "authenticated()".
But i don't know what is the correct way to use spring security in a stateless application =/

Comment: @CezarCruz yes stateless session is the culprit, switching to something else does not seem right since you are then testing something different from your real application.